# Android device videos using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap with an Android device and I need to display the device's videos.

Do anyone know how I should do that?

This is my code:

```
function getPhoto(source) { 
// Retrieve image file location from specified source 
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
   destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: source });
}
```

but it is only works with Pictures.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code?
StackOverflow is not a site that churns out samples on request. However, we'll gladly help you if you show you've put some effort into it yourself, first.

Comment: I tried this:
function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

Comment: but it it only working with pictures

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, it's hard to read in a comment.
Also, take a look at the [`Camera options` documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions_options) for Phonegap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap offers a MediaType in Camera.options

```
Camera.MediaType = { 
  PICTURE: 0,             // allow selection of still pictures only. DEFAULT. Will return format specified via DestinationType
  VIDEO: 1,               // allow selection of video only, WILL ALWAYS RETURN FILE_URI
  ALLMEDIA : 2            // allow selection from all media types
}
```

*"MediaType: Set the type of media to select from. Only works when PictureSourceType is PHOTOLIBRARY or SAVEDPHOTOALBUM. Defined in nagivator.camera.MediaType (Number)"*